# Run a python script in the future

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have got a python script which needs to be run on the user inputs. I will get the date and time from user and the script will run at that date.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today() 
enter_date = raw_input("Please enter a date:(2017-11-28): ")
enter_time = raw_input("What time do you want to start the script? ")

difference = enter_date - today

time.sleep(difference)
```

After this point main() function will run.

I could not make it run. Is there any better way to achieve this task ? Thanks

Comment: Create a task in the OS to run the script

Comment: `enter_date` is a string, you need to convert it to a date object before computing the difference.

Comment: Are you on windows or linux (unix)?

Comment: If you are learning Python, you would do well to target Python 3. The old version was already slated to be end-of-lifed next year, though the deadline was extended by a couple of years because pick-up was slow a couple of years ago.  There is no good reason to remain on Python 2 if you are not maintaining legacy scripts.

Comment: You can use `sched` python module from the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sched.html

Comment: @isma I am using windows 7. thanks

Comment: @pydev, program is good but way to solve it is bad idea, i would suggest you take the time from user and write it in a file (say `schedule.txt`) against the file name which has to be executed. Setup a cron to run a python script which read from `schedule.txt` and invokes the program internally!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

date_format = "%d/%m/%y %H:%M"
today = datetime.today() 

print("Please enter date in format dd/mm/yy HH:MM")

enter_date = datetime.strptime(
    raw_input("> "),
    date_format)

difference = enter_date - today

print(difference)


#time.sleep(difference.total_seconds())
```

Uncomment sleep if you want. However this is a bad solution. You should OS specific features to do that. For example you could add line with you script to cronjob file on linux etc. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Answer (score 2):

Asumming you can execute cron jobs, a nice solution would be to split your script in two parts, one to request when the script will be executed and the other one the actual script.

Your first script will create a cron job to schedule the execution of the  script, for that you can use the python-crontab package:

```
pip install python-crontab
```

To create the cron job:

```
from datetime import datetime
from crontab import CronTab

run_date_input = raw_input("Please enter a date (e.g. 2017-11-28): ")
run_time_input = raw_input("What time do you want to start the script (e.g. 14:30:12)? ")

run_date = datetime.strptime(run_date_input, "%y-%m-%d")
run_time = datetime.strptime(run_time_input, "%H:%M:%S")

#Access the crontab for the current user (on unix systems)
user_cron = CronTab(user='your username')

#Access the crontab (on windows sytems)
user_cron = CronTab(tabfile='c:/path_to_your_tab_file/filename.tab')

#Create a new job
job = user_cron.new(command='python /home/your_second_script.py')
job.setall(datetime(run_date.year, run_date.month, run_date.day, run_time.hour, run_time.minute, run_time.second))
```

If you use windows you need to install cron for windows using something like [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or the new Linux subsystem for Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Isma

Comment: You can run python-crontab on windows as a service if you like. (more testing would be great) see https://github.com/doctormo/python-crontab#running-the-scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today() 
input_date = raw_input("Please enter a date and time : 2017-12-31 18:02 : ")

enter_date=datetime.strptime(input_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

difference = enter_date - today

print difference.total_seconds()

time.sleep(difference.total_seconds())
```

if you want to take date and time separate then use

```
import time
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.today() 
input_date = raw_input("Please enter a date 2017-12-31  : ")
input_time=raw_input("What time do you want to start the script? 18:02 : ")

enter_date=datetime.datetime.strptime(input_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
enter_time=input_time.split(':')
date_with_time = enter_date + datetime.timedelta(hours=int(enter_time[0]),minutes=int(enter_time[1]))

difference = date_with_time - today

print difference.total_seconds()

time.sleep(difference.total_seconds())
```

But the preferred way would be to use cron jobs [find more here about cron](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)